# Cannot fire event on non-text region when tap&hold to show the contextmenu in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, contextmenu

I want to add the context menu to ListBox in WP7, I modify the data template as following below:

```
<ListBox Name="lbx1" Margin="10,0,10,0" Height="435"  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle1}" FontSize="40" Tap="lbx1_Tap" >
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                        <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Copy" Click="ListBoxGeneralCopy_Click"/>
                                        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding .}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

I can only cause tap and hold event to show the contextmenu above the text, the non-text region could not cause the event, I really confused. Does someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your textbloc will only occupy so much space as necessary. Therefore your stackpanel will also only be as wide as necessary.

You can set the HorizontalAlignment-value of both to stretch so it occupies the whole width:

```
<ListBox Name="lbx1" Margin="10,0,10,0" Height="435"  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle1}" FontSize="40" Tap="lbx1_Tap" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Copy" Click="ListBoxGeneralCopy_Click"/>
                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding .}"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Sorry, the space does not contain in the text block, I mean I can only fire the event on the words, but I cannot fire the event on the same listbox item place with non-words-region.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying. Since your textBlock and consequentially your StackPanel do not take up all the space when you tap and hold, you're actually tapping outside of the StackPanel and thus the event never gets raised and your contextmenu doesn't show up

Comment: That`s fine. Finally, I change the ListboxItem style "HorizontalContentAlignment" and "HorizontalAlignment" to "Stretch". And it is works fine. Thank you for helping me, Kenneth.

Answer (score 0):

Set StackPanel background property.
When background is transparent cannot work, and hold event is fired only in non-transparent region of stackpanel such as text-regions.